# PHP Passing variable in URL

Tags: php

Im trying to pass a variable in the URL and to post the variable on the page. I currently have a table and a variable named `$record['Filename']`. The value is not displaying correctly.

Right now I have the following

```
while($record = mysql_fetch_array($mydata)){ 
    echo "<tr>"; 
    echo "<td>" ."<a href='Info.html?page='.$record['Filename'].> $record['Filename'] </a>". " </td>";
    echo "<td>" . $record['Description'] . "</td>";

    echo "</tr>"; 
}
```

Comment: and what is your question ?

Comment: you cannot embed php-in-php, and using quoted array keys in a `"`-quoted string is bad php, unless you use the `{}` extended syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP strings 101:

```
echo "<td>" ."<a href='Info.html?page='.$record['Filename'].> $record['Filename'] </a>". " </td>";
             ^--start string                                             end string --^
```

Since you never "exit" your `"`-quoted strings, your `.` are just plaintext periods, not concatenation operators.

You probably want this:

```
    echo <<<EOL
<td><a href="Info.html?page={$record['Filename']}">{$record['Filename']}</a></td>
EOL;
```

Notice how using a [heredoc](http://php.net/heredoc) removes the need to hop in/out of string mode, and you can use proper quoting in the HTML. Also note the `{}`-extended string syntax around the variables.

Answer (score 0):

try to change,

```
<a href='Info.html?page='.$record['Filename'].> $record['Filename'] </a>
```

to

```
<a href="Info.html?page=<?php echo $record['Filename'];?>"> <?php echo $record['Filename'];?> </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes instead of double quotes. It's faster and more efficient.

```
while($record = mysql_fetch_array($mydata)){ 
    echo '<tr>'; 
    echo '<td><a href="Info.html?page='.$record['Filename'].'">'.$record['Filename'].'</a></td>';
    echo '<td>'. $record['Description'].'</td>';
    echo '</tr>'; 
}
```

Comment: the processing time difference between `"` and `'` strings is essentially zero, unless you're running a facebook-sized operation.

Comment: That's why I mentioned that ;)
Essentially zero here, essentially zero there and overall we're having significant time to save.